# Google Sheet - Query to display date and value of earliest date from the given list

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, vlookup

I am trying to fetch value first day of every month.

```
02/06/2000 15:30:00 5.12
05/06/2000 15:30:00 5.2
06/06/2000 15:30:00 5.28
07/06/2000 15:30:00 5.26
08/06/2000 15:30:00 5.33
09/06/2000 15:30:00 5.36
12/06/2000 15:30:00 5.24
13/06/2000 15:30:00 5.33
14/06/2000 15:30:00 5.39
15/06/2000 15:30:00 5.3
16/06/2000 15:30:00 5.29
19/06/2000 15:30:00 5.27
20/06/2000 15:30:00 5.26
21/06/2000 15:30:00 5.33
22/06/2000 15:30:00 5.25
23/06/2000 15:30:00 5.15
26/06/2000 15:30:00 5.21
27/06/2000 15:30:00 5.15
28/06/2000 15:30:00 5.09
29/06/2000 15:30:00 5.11
30/06/2000 15:30:00 4.82
03/07/2000 15:30:00 4.87
04/07/2000 15:30:00 4.92
05/07/2000 15:30:00 4.87
06/07/2000 15:30:00 4.93
07/07/2000 15:30:00 4.85
10/07/2000 15:30:00 5.2
11/07/2000 15:30:00 5.43
12/07/2000 15:30:00 5.54
13/07/2000 15:30:00 5.29
14/07/2000 15:30:00 5.17
17/07/2000 15:30:00 5.29
18/07/2000 15:30:00 5.07
19/07/2000 15:30:00 5.05
20/07/2000 15:30:00 4.92
21/07/2000 15:30:00 5.04
24/07/2000 15:30:00 4.77
25/07/2000 15:30:00 4.91
26/07/2000 15:30:00 4.62
27/07/2000 15:30:00 4.8
28/07/2000 15:30:00 4.59
31/07/2000 15:30:00 4.47
01/08/2000 15:30:00 4.57
02/08/2000 15:30:00 4.51
03/08/2000 15:30:00 4.57
04/08/2000 15:30:00 4.41
07/08/2000 15:30:00 4.3
08/08/2000 15:30:00 4.35
09/08/2000 15:30:00 4.35
10/08/2000 15:30:00 4.33
11/08/2000 15:30:00 4.3
14/08/2000 15:30:00 4.26
16/08/2000 15:30:00 4.26
17/08/2000 15:30:00 4.25
18/08/2000 15:30:00 4.28
21/08/2000 15:30:00 4.36
22/08/2000 15:30:00 4.39
23/08/2000 15:30:00 4.44
24/08/2000 15:30:00 4.45
25/08/2000 15:30:00 4.52
28/08/2000 15:30:00 4.68
29/08/2000 15:30:00 4.71
30/08/2000 15:30:00 4.68
31/08/2000 15:30:00 4.79
04/09/2000 15:30:00 4.8
05/09/2000 15:30:00 4.71
06/09/2000 15:30:00 4.72
07/09/2000 15:30:00 4.73
08/09/2000 15:30:00 4.79
11/09/2000 15:30:00 4.87
12/09/2000 15:30:00 4.83
13/09/2000 15:30:00 4.73
14/09/2000 15:30:00 4.77
15/09/2000 15:30:00 5.13
18/09/2000 15:30:00 5.1
19/09/2000 15:30:00 5.1
20/09/2000 15:30:00 5.13
21/09/2000 15:30:00 5.12
22/09/2000 15:30:00 5.46
25/09/2000 15:30:00 5.57
26/09/2000 15:30:00 5.32
27/09/2000 15:30:00 5.32
28/09/2000 15:30:00 5.48
29/09/2000 15:30:00 5.9
03/10/2000 15:30:00 6.08
04/10/2000 15:30:00 6.07
05/10/2000 15:30:00 6.3
06/10/2000 15:30:00 6.52
09/10/2000 15:30:00 6.39
10/10/2000 15:30:00 6.1
11/10/2000 15:30:00 6.06
12/10/2000 15:30:00 6.12
13/10/2000 15:30:00 6.47
16/10/2000 15:30:00 6.42
17/10/2000 15:30:00 6.23
18/10/2000 15:30:00 6.2
19/10/2000 15:30:00 6.68
20/10/2000 15:30:00 7.18
23/10/2000 15:30:00 6.86
24/10/2000 15:30:00 6.89
25/10/2000 15:30:00 7.29
26/10/2000 15:30:00 7.42
27/10/2000 15:30:00 7.33
30/10/2000 15:30:00 7.29
31/10/2000 15:30:00 7.33
01/11/2000 15:30:00 7.48
02/11/2000 15:30:00 7.57
03/11/2000 15:30:00 7.9
06/11/2000 15:30:00 8.11
07/11/2000 15:30:00 8.36
08/11/2000 15:30:00 8.31
09/11/2000 15:30:00 8.49
10/11/2000 15:30:00 8.58
13/11/2000 15:30:00 8.67
14/11/2000 15:30:00 8.65
15/11/2000 15:30:00 8.76
16/11/2000 15:30:00 8.77
17/11/2000 15:30:00 8.91
20/11/2000 15:30:00 9.03
21/11/2000 15:30:00 9.21
22/11/2000 15:30:00 9.19
23/11/2000 15:30:00 9.35
24/11/2000 15:30:00 9.59
27/11/2000 15:30:00 9.79
28/11/2000 15:30:00 9.98
29/11/2000 15:30:00 10.07
30/11/2000 15:30:00 10.15
01/12/2000 15:30:00 10.19
04/12/2000 15:30:00 10.4
05/12/2000 15:30:00 10.35
06/12/2000 15:30:00 10.95
07/12/2000 15:30:00 11.06
08/12/2000 15:30:00 11.32
11/12/2000 15:30:00 11.55
12/12/2000 15:30:00 11.43
13/12/2000 15:30:00 11.72
14/12/2000 15:30:00 11.71
15/12/2000 15:30:00 11.81
18/12/2000 15:30:00 12.07
19/12/2000 15:30:00 12.09
20/12/2000 15:30:00 12.28
21/12/2000 15:30:00 12.28
```

I want a query to display

```
02/06/2000  5.12
03/07/2000  4.87
01/08/2000  4.57
04/09/2000  4.8
03/10/2000  6.08
01/11/2000  7.48
01/12/2000  10.19
```

Presently, I am doing multiple sorting in different columns. Any simplified query suggestion will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(SORTN({A:A, C:C, TEXT(A:A, "e-mm")}, 9^9, 2, 3, 1), 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col2 is not null", )
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=QUERY(SORTN({
 GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "PRICE", DATE(2020,1,1), TODAY(), "DAILY"), TEXT(
 GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "PRICE", DATE(2020,1,1), TODAY(), "DAILY"), "e-mm")}, 9^9, 2, 3, 1), 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col2 is not null", )
```

[image]

Comment: Can we use googlefinance function directly instead of output of googlefinance function?

Comment: @SP160477 sure, whats you googlefinance function?

Comment: Please take same example as mike GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), today(), "DAILY")

Comment: @SP160477 answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Try it, assuming your data starts at line 2.

```
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(unique(EOMONTH(A2:A,-1)+1),sort({EOMONTH(A2:A,-1)+1,A2:A,C2:C}),{2,3},0)))
```

result (dates formatted dd/MM/yyyy)

with google finance, try

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(
text(unique(eomonth(sequence(today()-date(2020,1,1),1,date(2020,1,1),1),0)),"yyyy-MM"),
TEXT(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), today(), "DAILY"),{"yyyy-MM", "@"}),
{1,2},0))
```

[image]

### explanation

- `sequence(today()-date(2020,1,1),1,date(2020,1,1),1)` will give a list of all dates since 1/1/2020
- `text(unique(eomonth(___)))` will retain unique values as yyyy-MM [EOMONTH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093044)
- vlookup will search for each of the above value in googlefinance result (since 1/1/2020) in which dates have been transformed as yyyy-MM

Comment: Can we use googlefinance function directly instead of output of googlefinance function?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry if I sound pretty naive. Can you please give an explanation of the function used?

Comment: Done, let me know if it is understandable!

Comment: Yes.. This is absolutely fine.. Thanks a lot