# Google Sheet: Fetch earliest date and average of value of month from the list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average, number-formatting, google-query-language

Below is the data:

```
02/06/2000 15:30:00 5.12
05/06/2000 15:30:00 5.2
06/06/2000 15:30:00 5.28
07/06/2000 15:30:00 5.26
08/06/2000 15:30:00 5.33
09/06/2000 15:30:00 5.36
12/06/2000 15:30:00 5.24
13/06/2000 15:30:00 5.33
14/06/2000 15:30:00 5.39
15/06/2000 15:30:00 5.3
16/06/2000 15:30:00 5.29
19/06/2000 15:30:00 5.27
20/06/2000 15:30:00 5.26
21/06/2000 15:30:00 5.33
22/06/2000 15:30:00 5.25
23/06/2000 15:30:00 5.15
26/06/2000 15:30:00 5.21
27/06/2000 15:30:00 5.15
28/06/2000 15:30:00 5.09
29/06/2000 15:30:00 5.11
30/06/2000 15:30:00 4.82
03/07/2000 15:30:00 4.87
04/07/2000 15:30:00 4.92
05/07/2000 15:30:00 4.87
06/07/2000 15:30:00 4.93
07/07/2000 15:30:00 4.85
10/07/2000 15:30:00 5.2
11/07/2000 15:30:00 5.43
12/07/2000 15:30:00 5.54
13/07/2000 15:30:00 5.29
14/07/2000 15:30:00 5.17
17/07/2000 15:30:00 5.29
18/07/2000 15:30:00 5.07
19/07/2000 15:30:00 5.05
20/07/2000 15:30:00 4.92
21/07/2000 15:30:00 5.04
24/07/2000 15:30:00 4.77
25/07/2000 15:30:00 4.91
26/07/2000 15:30:00 4.62
27/07/2000 15:30:00 4.8
28/07/2000 15:30:00 4.59
31/07/2000 15:30:00 4.47
01/08/2000 15:30:00 4.57
02/08/2000 15:30:00 4.51
03/08/2000 15:30:00 4.57
04/08/2000 15:30:00 4.41
07/08/2000 15:30:00 4.3
08/08/2000 15:30:00 4.35
09/08/2000 15:30:00 4.35
10/08/2000 15:30:00 4.33
11/08/2000 15:30:00 4.3
14/08/2000 15:30:00 4.26
16/08/2000 15:30:00 4.26
17/08/2000 15:30:00 4.25
18/08/2000 15:30:00 4.28
21/08/2000 15:30:00 4.36
22/08/2000 15:30:00 4.39
23/08/2000 15:30:00 4.44
24/08/2000 15:30:00 4.45
25/08/2000 15:30:00 4.52
28/08/2000 15:30:00 4.68
29/08/2000 15:30:00 4.71
30/08/2000 15:30:00 4.68
31/08/2000 15:30:00 4.79
```

I want to have an average of the individual months like:

```
06/2000 5.225
07/2000 4.98
08/2000 4.44
```

Right now, I am using multiple columns which include multiple fucntions for getting this data. Query by using googlefinance function raw data will be highly appreciable.
Thanks in advance.
Best Regards

Comment: When you expect average of month but your expected result showing particular day of month. It should be like `06/2000`, `07/2000`, `08/2000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(
 {TEXT(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), TODAY(), "DAILY"), "mm/e"),
  TEXT(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), TODAY(), "DAILY"), {"e-m-1", "#.#0"})*1}, 
 "offset 1", ), "select Col1,avg(Col4) group by Col3,Col1 label avg(Col4)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: It returns the same value as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375986/google-sheet-query-to-display-date-and-value-of-earliest-date-from-the-given-l, and not the average of individual month

Comment: @SP160477 fixed. answer updated

Comment: This update works perfectly fine..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by a pivot table

Group dates by year-month

[image]

Comment: What if we use googlefinance fucntion data?

Comment: I do it in A1 `=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2020,1,1), today(), "DAILY")`